# Ballistic Electrons in Ballistic Electron Emission Microscopy (BEEM)

Tags: nanoscience

This is for an exam that i have in the near future.
Would someone be able to explain what a Ballistic electron is in terms of BEEM. From my understanding ballistic would mean only acted upon by gravity.Can someone either correct me or expand on what i said if its right.
Thank you

Comment: See [ballistic conduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_conduction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use BEEM everyday. "Ballistic Electron" in this sense means that the electron is able to go travel between two scattering events and remain unscattered in a metal. There is a lot of high level theory that can go into describing the motion of these electrons in a BEEM measurement, but generally you should think of it as an electron that is not scattered in a metal as it conducts through the metal to the semiconductor interface.

What you describe as "Ballistic" motion is really just projectile motion of an object and that its an object that is given some energy and it falls in a parabolic arc.

In depth answer: In a metal electronic states are occupied up to and at the fermi level of the metal. This means that electrons as they conduct through a metal must scatter into unoccupied states with energies of a few $k_bT$ (25meV) above or below the fermi level. So electrons as they conduct through the metal must have sufficient energy to scatter into these unoccupied states and generally have the same amount of energy. When you perform BEEM measurements though you are giving the electrons a boost to their kinetic energy by applying a bias between the STM tip and the metal, these electrons are now around a $1~eV$ higher than the fermi level of the metal and are considered "hot" electrons. "hot" electrons refer to the fact that when measuring energies in relation to $$E = k_bT$$ which at room temperature (300K) have an energy of 25meV, you have an energy of $1eV = k_b T$, $k_b$ is the boltzmann constant in eV, so your temperature of the electron is considered "hot" or 12000K. This is not a real temperature of the electron or of the material, but a guideline of the kinetic energy in relation to electrons conducting within a few k_b*T of the fermi level.

So these "hot" electrons have a lot of energy and because of this their scattering interactions are different. An electron with energy much greater than that of the fermi level is going to have more inelastic scattering events such as electron electron scattering and less energy loss from phonon interactions since electron-phonon energy loss is on the order of $k_bT$. If these electrons travel through the metal without very few scattering events they are considered "ballistic" electrons.

de Andres, P. L., F. J. Garcia-Vidal, K. Reuter, and F. Flores, 2001, Prog. Surf. Sci. 66, 3.

D. A. Pearson and L. J. Sham, Theory of ballistic electron emission microscopy. Phys. Rev. B 2001, 64, 125408. http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.64.125408

http://www.rug.nl/research/portal/files/2372254/Chapter_2.pdf